# Given 2d array of integers, find a path that sum up to a given number recursively

Tags: java, recursion

Given a 2d array, I need to return a matrix with a path that sum up to a given number, recursively.

the path matrix should be zeros except for the path that sums up to the given number which will be marked with 1.

A path could only go left/right up/down in the

I have tried to go over all the possibilities, checking first if I already been to the next block.

the problem is that after some iterations it stops, and doesnt go back and clear the block to be 0 again.

```
private static boolean paintPath(int[][] mat, int sum, int[][] path , int i, int j){

        if(sum<0)
            return false;

        path[i][j] = 1;

        if(sum == 0)
            return true;
        printMat(path);
        System.out.println();

        if(withinBoundaries(mat,i+1,j) && path[i+1][j] != 1)
            if(paintPath(mat,sum - mat[i][j],path,i+1,j))
                return true;

        if(withinBoundaries(mat,i,j+1) && path[i][j+1] != 1)
            if(paintPath(mat,sum - mat[i][j],path,i,j+1))
                return true;

        if(withinBoundaries(mat,i-1,j) && path[i-1][j] != 1)
            if(paintPath(mat,sum - mat[i][j],path,i-1,j))
                return true;
        if(withinBoundaries(mat,i,j-1) && path[i][j-1] != 1)
            if(paintPath(mat,sum - mat[i][j],path,i,j-1))
                 return true;

        path[i][j] = 0;
        return false;

    }
```

given

```
int[][] mat1 = {
                {1,1,1,1},
                {5,100,100,1},
                {100,100,100,1},
                {1,1,1,1}
        };


 int[][] path = {
                {0,0,0,0},
                {0,0,0,0},
                {0,0,0,0},
                {0,0,0,0}
        };
```

with the call

```
paintPath(mat1, 5, path, 0, 0);
```

I expected the algorithm to return

```
        {0,0,0,0},
        {1,0,0,0},
        {0,0,0,0},
        {0,0,0,0}
```

I get

```
1   1   1   1   
0   0   1   1   
0   0   0   0   
0   0   0   0
```

Instead.

And from a call to paintPath(mat1, 400, path, 0, 0);
I expect

```
        {0,0,0,0},
        {0,1,1,0},
        {0,1,1,0},
        {0,0,0,0}
```

or

```
        {0,0,0,0},
        {0,0,1,0},
        {1,1,1,0},
        {0,0,0,0}
```

The problem is that my algorithm start from (0,0) and look for a path from there, I need it to find *any* path from any start point (without a loop)

edit: 
The problem quoted from the assignment:
"We define a path in an array as a collection of adjacent cells.
adjacent cekks can be adjacent from left,right,up,down but not diagonal.
each cell can accure in the path only once.
write a recursive method, which accepts a 2d array mat which contains integers greater than 0, an integer sum poisitive number, and a 2d array path same size as mat.

the method is requierd to check if there is a path in the array that the sum of it values equals to sum.
if there is such a path it should return true, false otherwize.

the array path is used to mark the path that it sum euquals to sum.

path will have 1's where in the path cells and 0s in the other cells.

The method must be reccursive without loops at all!
so as any other method you will write.

you can use overloading.

you cannot change mat.

Comment: can you pleace explain in detail, path from where to where must have what summ??

Comment: @user8426627 (I cant seem to format it properly, paste it to a text editor to read)
 I guess the path from any starting point to any other point that sums up to a given number.
for example given the number 10 and the following matrix-
`
{1,2,3,1},
{5,8,7,15},
{1,2,3,4},
{1,1,1,1}
`
he wants to get any of the following-
`
0   1   0   0  
0   1   0   0   
0   0   0   0   
0   0   0   0
`
or
`
0   0   0   0  
0   1   0   0   
0   1   0   0   
0   0   0   0
`
etc...

Comment: he needs to have pairs(start, end) as output, not this nonsence matrix, and the task is heavy  cubic O(n^3) to n ~ matrix dimension, does it have practical task or is just useles?

Comment: The output is a path matrix, i added some examples hope it clarifies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this

```
path[i][j] = 1;

if(sum == 0)
  return true;
printMat(path);
System.out.println();
```

to this:

```
if(sum == 0){
  printMat(path);
  System.out.println();
  return true;
}

path[i][j] = 1;
```

Note that you would get the output,

```
{0,0,0,0},
{1,0,0,0},
{0,0,0,0},
{0,0,0,0}
```

if you changed the starting call to

```
paintPath(mat1, 5, path, 1, 0);
```

Comment: I wrote some more explanation, I need it to find the path from the same starting location (0,0) and not (1,0). i added some more examples so the task will be easier to understand. Thanks!

Comment: That was just a side note, this answer does solve your problem. You need to check `sum == 0` before setting the path flag to 1.

Comment: @OmerSegal the first part of my answer also addresses an error in your code that results in wrong solutions being returned. With that fix, your current function works for any given starting point in the first call. The problem you are now presenting has changed -- please clarify the requirements. We could solve "not using a loop," by using this working function with another recursive function that would just try each starting point. To understand why not, more details are needed. If the problem was provided to you, like as an assignment or listed on a website, you could quote the full details.

Comment: @גלעדברקן I added the question from the assignment, hope it clarifies

Comment: Iterating with recursion fixed it, Thanks!

Comment: can you optimize this using DP? Will sum be a parameter in DP array?

Comment: @AJ.S if we can think of overlapping subproblems then I would think so. I'm not sure what the exact definition of the task is, though.

Comment: @גלעדברקן finding a path with given sum, can this be done using dp[row_idx][col_idx][sum_achieved] - true if path exist from 0,0 to (row_idx,col_idx) and has sum sum_achieved?

Comment: @AJ.S if you could repeat cells in any one path then yes, but this problem is different since a cell can only be used once in a valid path. One thing I can think of to mark overlapping subproblems could be partial paths, but for larger data, I think the problem may get unwieldy fast.